# Subplot with equal aspect ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot 2 subplots in the same row with the same aspect ratio. It's quite ugly otherwise !

So, usually, I'm using `axes().set_aspect('equal')` (because I want ALSO to remove the axis, and I can't use 'off' AND 'equal') from pylab but it doesn't work right here, only the 2nd picture appears

My code:

```
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.tricontourf(x_exp, y_exp, z_exp)
plt.colorbar(shrink=0.9,drawedges=True, orientation='vertical')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('tricontour')

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.tricontourf(x_exp, y_exp, z_exp2)
plt.colorbar(shrink=0.9,drawedges=True, orientation='vertical')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('tricontour')

plt.show()
```

It could probably work with the following line but subplot doesn't have the `tricontourf` plot !

`fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1, adjustable='box', aspect=0.3)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)`

**Do you have an idea to figure out that ?**

EDIT:
[Sample of data](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08253078549567095176)

I have used `np.savez("Sample",x_exp=x_exp,y_exp=y_exp,z_exp=z_exp,z_exp2=z_exp2)`to save the data.

You can read it with the following lines:

```
import numpy as np
Data = np.load("Sample.npz")
x_exp = Data['x_exp']
y_exp = Data['y_exp']
z_exp = Data['z_exp']
z_exp2 = Data['z_exp2']
```

Comment: could you post a sample of `x_exp`, `y_exp`, `z_exp` and `z_exp2`?

Comment: Sure. I'm trying to figure out how, 1sec.

Comment: let me know if my answer below is what you are after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do what you want. I define each axes as subplots of the figure and change their properties to get an `equal` aspect ratio and to turn them off:

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
im = ax1.tricontourf(x_exp, y_exp, z_exp)
plt.colorbar(im, drawedges=True, orientation='vertical')
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
ax1.set_axis_off()
ax1.set_title('tricontour')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
im = ax2.tricontourf(x_exp, y_exp, z_exp2)
plt.colorbar(im, drawedges=True, orientation='vertical')
ax2.set_aspect('equal')
ax2.set_axis_off()
ax2.set_title('tricontour')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Perfect ! As simple as that !
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the same functionality. You can set aspect ratio of all the subplots by passing `subplots_kw=dict(<kw arguments for plt.axes>)`

For example,

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3, subplot_kw=dict(box_aspect=1))
```