# Matplotlib aspect ratio of subplots with shared axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have three matplotlib subplots with some shared axes, and I would like to set the axis ratio for one of them.  I have tried the solution proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66793156/6843348 and it only affects one of the subplots while messing the others up.  Any suggestions?  My code is below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(12, 8),
                       gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [3, 1],
                                    'height_ratios': [1, 3],
                                    'wspace': 0.0,
                                    'hspace': 0.0},
                       sharex='col', sharey='row', 
                       subplot_kw=(dict(box_aspect=1) if False else None)) # Doesn't work when added

x, y = norm.rvs(size=10000), norm.rvs(size=10000) # Random data

ax[0][0].hist(x, bins=30)
ax[1][1].hist(y, bins=30, orientation='horizontal')
ax[1][0].hist2d(x, y, bins=[np.linspace(-4, 4, 30), np.linspace(-4, 4, 30)])

plt.show()
```

[image: Bad]

[Worse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr0hA.png)

Comment: Kindly have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633322/changing-aspect-ratio-of-subplots-in-matplotlib

Comment: You're making your figure with size (12,8) for a layout of effectively 4x4. If you want an aspect ratio of 1, wouldn't it be easiest to also start with a square figure, say of size (8,8) or something?

Comment: @RutgerKassies fair point, though am concerned that with title and labels, even with a square figure there will be problems

Comment: @flyakite thanks; that link is pretty dense; I think it advocates ```ax.set(adjustable="box-forced")``` but that returns ```ValueError: 'box-forced' is not a valid value for adjustable; supported values are 'box', 'datalim'```

Comment: @MisterMak: oh, I did not realize that the option is not supported any longer. I posted a work-around below.

Answer (score 1):

Since `adjustable='box-forced'` was apparently removed in recent matplotlib versions, you could use the following work-around and plot the main plot with some aspect ratio first and add the additional axes thereafter.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig, axMain = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))

x, y = norm.rvs(size=10000), norm.rvs(size=10000) # Random data

#main plot
axMain.hist2d(x, y, bins=[np.linspace(-4, 4, 30), np.linspace(-4, 4, 30)])
axMain.set_aspect(1)

#additional axes
divider = make_axes_locatable(axMain)
axx = divider.append_axes('top', 1.5, sharex=axMain)
axy = divider.append_axes('right', 1.5, sharey=axMain)

#hide shared axes
axx.xaxis.set_visible(False)
axy.yaxis.set_visible(False)

#plot the additional data
axx.hist(x, bins=30)
axy.hist(y, bins=30, orientation='horizontal')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Not as seamless as I had hoped, but gets the job done, though I need to add ```pad=0``` to the ```append_axes``` command.  Thanks!